# Turn 2D shape into a Point Cloud

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, point-clouds

A project I'm currently working on requires turning a 2D shape (simple but random 2D shape, typically a face extracted from another object, can be tilted) into a Point Cloud of some specific specs (thickness, point distance, density, etc.) for further process.

So the idea I came up with is using Geometry Nodes to:

1. use Extrude Mesh node to turn the 2D shape into a 3D geometry
2. generate a box shaped point cloud bigger enough to cover the entire geometry
3. use the method from this tutourial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8pI_f-S6bg to delete all the points outside of the geometry

However, I get some fairly weird artifacts, as you can see in the attached screenshots. So besides those points inside the 'boundary', there are also some bits outside of the boundary somehow didn't get deleted as expected.
I can swap the 'boundary' geometry to some default meta shapes (cube, torus, etc.), and the whole thing works just fine.
[image: A simple 2D plane]
[image: The entire node tree]
[image: The 'Point Cloud' node group]
[image: The weird result]

Any idea of why it acts like that, and how I can fix it?

(I know I didn't close the bottom of the extruded mesh, but that's not the issue and doesn't help either as I've tried.)

Here's the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rLv0_lpGD8k9FVskyj3TkI3ukkh5WNZS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I wonder if this is actually a bug.

Comment: Note: in my actual case, the point cloud is more complicated and has a specific pattern, so it is made separately, hence why I took that 'boundary-check-remove-excesses' approach... Also the actual face will very likely be tilted with its normal facing all sorts of direction but its Z axis, but the point cloud (in its own pattern) does need to align with that face's normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transform a two-dimensional shape into a point cloud, you can use the following setup:

[image]

Here I extrude the 2D shape to get a solid body.

But instead of creating a grid, and removing the excess points, I use the nodes `Mesh to Volume` and `Distribute Points in Volume` to create points in a grid within this mesh.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

---

**Update**

In your specific use case or based on your example, you can also simply use the node `Raycast` and send a ray upwards. This way you filter all points that do not hit a surface:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate it. In my actual case though, the point cloud is more complicated and has a specific pattern, so it is made separately, hence why I took that 'removing' approach... Also the actual face will very likely be tilted with its normal facing all sorts of directions but its axis, making distributing points in it a bit tricky.

Comment: @Raven Ah, all right, maybe the suggestion in the update will help you.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked well in my actual case. I can use the face normal to direct the ray's direction. Never fully understood how Raycast works, but the outcome is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @Raven Imagine that with `Raycast` simply a ray is sent from a certain position in a certain direction. If the ray hits an obstacle, a *Hit* is generated, and you have additional information about the point that was hit (normal, position, distance, etc.).